# How to Manage Grouped Row Counts

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework-core

In dealing with SQL Server (via Entity Framework Core 3) and have a requirement to add members to a group, but with a limit to the number of members allowed in each group.  I will illustrate:

Table Structure:

```
[ID] [bigint] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL, 
[MemberId] [bigint] NOT NULL, 
[GroupNumber] [bigint] NOT NULL, 
[PositionInGroup] [int] NOT NULL
```

Every time I add a new row to this table, I need to calculate the "GroupNumber" and "PositionInGroup" for the new member.  Each "GroupNumber" may only have 5 Members in it.

So, when adding a new record, I need to...

1. Get the largest value for "GroupNumber" number
2. Count number of people in GroupNumber
3. Increase PositionInGroup in GroupNumber, and roll-over to "0" if greater than 5 (max allowed in group)
4. If position in group is zero (i.e. we rolled over), increase GroupNumber by 1
5. Create new record with GroupNumbernumber and PositionInGroup value

Since there are a number of calculations that need to happen based on rows in the table, what's the best way to manage this in SQL Server (or EF Core Framework) to prevent members being assigned incorrect/duplicate group/position numbers due to simultaneous group add requests?

Is this kind of thing best handled with transactions or some kind of atomic insert?  If this should be handled via transaction, which Isolation level is most appropriate?

If it matters, I expect no more than 500 of these calls across a 12 hour period, so I'm not super worried about lock contention - I care primarily about data integrity.

Here is what I would expect the data to look like after 15 insertions.  Notice the "PositionInGroup" counter resets once the max PositionInGroup of 5 has been reached.

A member can only ever be in one group at one position.  Once a member is in a group at a specific position, it can never change. A member will only ever be added to this table exactly one time.

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Show some sample data and expected results. Its very hard to make sense of reading so much text.

Comment: Could a member be in more than 1 group?

Comment: No.  A member can only be in one group and at one position.

Answer (score 0):

Fun excersise. I'd go for computed columns to ensure full integrity.

You should link the actual user or whatever as a foreign key in this table, since it's vital that the memberId is sequential.

*setup/input*

```sql
DECLARE @test TABLE (
    memberId int identity(1,1),
    groupNumber as (memberId - 1) / 5 + 1
);

insert into @test default values
insert into @test default values
insert into @test default values
insert into @test default values
insert into @test default values
insert into @test default values
insert into @test default values
insert into @test default values
insert into @test default values
insert into @test default values
insert into @test default values
insert into @test default values
insert into @test default values
insert into @test default values
insert into @test default values

select *, 
  row_number() over (partition by groupNumber order by memberId) as positionInGroup
from @test
order by memberId
```

*output*

```
+----------+-------------+-----------------+
| memberId | groupNumber | positionInGroup |
+----------+-------------+-----------------+
|        1 |           1 |               1 |
|        2 |           1 |               2 |
|        3 |           1 |               3 |
|        4 |           1 |               4 |
|        5 |           1 |               5 |
|        6 |           2 |               1 |
|        7 |           2 |               2 |
|        8 |           2 |               3 |
|        9 |           2 |               4 |
|       10 |           2 |               5 |
|       11 |           3 |               1 |
|       12 |           3 |               2 |
|       13 |           3 |               3 |
|       14 |           3 |               4 |
|       15 |           3 |               5 |
+----------+-------------+-----------------+
```

Comment: Thanks for that!  What if it's not vital that the member id is sequential?  I.e. it could be any unique member id.  Does that change things?

Comment: it is very important for memberId to be identity(1,1), a number sequence without gaps starting from 1, otherwise the groupNumber and positionInGroup calculations will fail. but as I write, you could add any other entity by using a foreign key in this table.